# The hangman can't work properly when I press the on screen keyboard button

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

```
def game():
    global no_of_guesses
    no_of_guesses = 0
    imgLb.configure(image=photos[0])
    target_word = random.choice(list_of_words)
    lblword.set(' '.join('_'*len(target_word)))

def guess(letter):
    global no_of_guesses
    if no_of_guesses < 11:
        guessed = list(lblword.get())
        for c in range(len(guessed)):
            if guessed[c] == letter:
                lblword.set(''.join(guessed))
                messagebox.showinfo('Hangman','You guess correctly')
            else:
                no_of_guesses += 1
                imgLb.configure(image=photos[no_of_guesses])
                if no_of_guesses == 11:
                    messagebox.showwarning('Hangman','Game Over!')
                
           
imgLb = Label(win)
imgLb.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=3,padx=10,pady=40)
imgLb.configure(image=photos[0])

lblword = StringVar()
WordLb = Label(win,textvariable=lblword)
WordLb.grid(row=0,column=3,columnspan=6,padx=10)

n = 0
for char in ascii_uppercase:
    Button(win,text=char,command=lambda char=char:guess(char),width=4).grid(row=1+n//9,column=n%9)
    n += 1
```

Error:

```
    Exception in Tkinter callback
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
        return self.func(*args)
      File "E:/Python/Python Projects Fun/hangman/hangman_code.py", line 52, in <lambda>
        Button(win,text=char,command=lambda char=char:guess(char),width=4).grid(row=1+n//9,column=n%9)
      File "E:/Python/Python Projects Fun/hangman/hangman_code.py", line 37, in guess
        imgLb.configure(image=photos[no_of_guesses])
    IndexError: list index out of range
```

I tried many times and when I press the button once the error came out and sometimes does not recognize the correct word. However sometimes when I press the button once then the whole hangman came out. Anyone know how to solve the above problem? Now for this problem, I already fix it by understanding the answer and tried to write once myself and finally the program works successfully.

Comment: For the `IndexError`, I'm guessing you'd want `photos[no_of_guesses - 1]` instead of `photos[no_of_guesses]` if len(photos)==11

Comment: I changed photos[no_of_guesses-1] and when I press the letter that not matched it shows the warning game over instead of doing 10 times guessing

Comment: Then I suggest you create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Instead I changed and already global no_of_guesses in the def game() and still error message: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'no_of_guesses' referenced before assignment

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you want the function to be lambda but the character to be static. It is a good day for you as I have struggled to make an on screen keyboard as well. Note the aptly named function in the command.

```py
Button(win,text=char, command=partial(guess, char), width=4).grid(row=1+n//9, column=n%9)
```